# BTGuard Socks5 libtorrent qBittorrent Deluge trackers not updating stalled downloads

Tags: deluge, qbittorrent

I have been trying to use BTGuard with Ubuntu/Xubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 beta with Deluge, qBittorrent. However, the trackers never seem to update. On the same computer with Ubuntu/Xubuntu 12.04 there is no problems. When researching this problem, several other people are having this issue and some think the problem is with libtorrent and/or socks5 and/or UDP.

1. Does anyone know of a work-around for this problem?
2. How can I update qBittorrent and libtorrent to the latest versions on 13.04/13.10?
3. Has anyone gotten socks5 w/BTGuard to work on 13.04/13.10?

As an added note, qBittorrent was working intermittently with lots of stalls on 13.04 until a recent update. I'm not sure what changed. The latest version of Deluge w/BTGuard does not seem to work on 13.10, even though it appears to use more recent versions of Deluge and libtorrent. I have not tested any of this on 12.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in libtorrent, and may be fixed in latest version.  Not sure it has made it to ubuntu repos yet though.

https://code.google.com/p/libtorrent/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=439